# Connect L355 Epson to new router

Tags: wireless-networking, router, printer, connection

Epson no longer supports our L355 printer.

We have changed our broadband provider and have a new router.
I cannot find on internet how to connect old printer to new router. I did find something to follow but it was in Spanish.

Comment: Did you set it up with a Static IP on the old router?  That would most likely have changed with the new router

Comment: Check online for information on the printer using *Epson*, not *Epsom* in the search, e.g., https://files.support.epson.com/pdf/elink/cpd37652.pdf

Answer (score 2):

As per the [User Guide](https://files.support.epson.com/pdf/l355__/l355__ug.pdf):

Press the WPS button on the router. Press the Wi-Fi button on the printer within 2 minutes of pressing the WPS button on your router. Hold down the Wi-Fi button on the printer for 3 seconds. That should connect the printer to the new router.

Alternatively, you can set its IP address using [EpsonNet Config](https://epsonnet-config.en.lo4d.com/windows), a free utility.